# Phonegap Load Remote JSON error occuring

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I am trying to load a remote .JS file with JSON data in Phonegap.

```
$.ajax(
  {
    url: "http://dev.indielongbox.com/js/json/json.js",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr + status + error);
    }
  }
);
```

I am getting [object Object] as the error, I have validated my JSON.

Comment: The error cannot be output the way you are trying because `xhr` and `status` and `error` are all objects. Try using `console.log(error)` or `alert(error.message)`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably too things happening. First, you are printing the error message the wrong way and thus is *[object Object]* printed. The problem is that you are trying to alert an object which always yields that string. Instead, what you should be doing is to check the *xhr.status* as follows

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.status);
}
```

The second thing, that actually is the reason why error callback is called, is that the cross-domain requests aren't allowed. You can see [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) for ways to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to make the CORS enabled.